# Expressão equivalente a "lose one's temper" in English?

Tags: expressões, tradução, vocabulário, termos-em-inglês

Apologies for writing my question in English, but I am not sure I will be able to express the nuance in Portuguese.

The expression *lose one's temper* in English carries a connotation of no longer being in control of oneself, i.e. Becoming angry to the extent that you are almost physically unable to stop yourself from behaving a certain way.

Would the expression "Eu não estou perdendo a calma" carry the same connotation as  "I am not losing my temper" ?  i.e. , I may be annoyed, but I am not past the point of reason.

Google translate suggests "Eu não estou perdendo meu temperamento". But I have never heard this expression. Does it fit?

Are either of these exact matches, and if not, what connotation do they carry?  Or are there better alternatives?

Muito obrigado. Eu vou ser feliz com respostas em português ou inglês, porque eu sei entender melhor do que sei escrever.

Comment: Welcome to the community! You can write your question in weak portuguese, and we will help with correcting it. :) You can also write it in english. Both options are perfectly fine.

Comment: Some_Guy vejo que já domina mais o português :)

Comment: Google translate is terrible for this kind of thing. To lose's one temper means get angry: ficar zangado.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As expressões mais próximas de ***losing one's temper*** que me vêm à cabeça, em português, são **perder a calma**, como você sugeriu, ou também **perder a cabeça**.

Além dessas, há a expressão **perder as estribeiras** que tem o mesmo significado, é menos formal, mas é muito popular. Quer dizer perder o controle emocional. Veja abaixo algumas definições:

- [Perder as estribeiras - no Dicionário inFormal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/perder%20as%20estribeiras/)
- [Perder as estribeiras - no Guia do Estudante Abril](http://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/aventuras-historia/perder-estribeiras-436076.shtml)

Este último link também mostra a origem da expressão:

> Quando uma pessoa se descontrola ou fica momentaneamente desatinada, dizemos que ela “perdeu as estribeiras”. A origem dessa expressão está nos jogos europeus de cavalaria dos séculos 15 a 17. Literalmente, perder as estribeiras significava ficar sem contato com os estribos, aros que pendem de cada lado da sela do cavalo e são utilizados como ponto de apoio para o pé do cavaleiro.

Outra expressão bem comum com o mesmo significado, também informal, é **Tirar alguém do sério.**.

Já a expressão **Eu não estou perdendo meu temperamento** é uma tradução literal que não parece se aplicar ao contexto. Soa um tanto estranha. Se aplicaria mais a uma situação em que a pessoa está tendo mudanças na personalidade.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  To me, "perder as estribeiras" conveys the same as "perder a calma" but is rarely used by people of a "polite upbringing", though. I may be wrong but I feel there is some class distinction in its usage.

Comment: I guess that it's an expression used mainly in the countryside, given the references to horses and all. I agree that it's not used as much in the large cities.

Comment: Ricardo, on second thoughts I see a difference between "perder a calma" and "perder a cabeça".   "Perder a calma" means exactly "to lose one's temper".  "Perder a cabeça", however, means to lose one's reason. examples: "Ela perdeu a calma e começou a gritar".  "Ele perdeu a calma e deu um soco no cliente."  "Ele perdeu a cabeça e foi morar com aquela mulher que ele mal conhece"  Ele perdeu a cabeça e está vendendo tudo o que tem para poder viajar". Of course you can also use "perdeu a cabeça" when one does something unexpected during an outburst of anger. Ele perdeu a cabeça e atirou nela

Comment: Eu estou habituado à expressão "perder as estribeiras" em contexto **citadino**, e tanto formal como informal.

Comment: Dependendo do caso pode ser "perder a paciência".

Comment: Saltar a tampa também é uma expressão. Passei-me também é bastante utilizado. Pelo menos aqui no sul.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - Hehe - essa eu nunca ouvi, mas quero a usar :D Como eu a utilizaria numa frase? *Aquele cara saltou a tampa?*

Comment: @Ricardo Não. Usas assim: "Aquele filho da p**a fez-me saltar a tampa!" ou "Sai daqui antes que salte-me a tampa!"

Comment: Claro, perder o temperamento é bobagem como tradução....:). Perder a cabeça ou calma.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps also worth mentioning is ***perder a compostura***.

Where *compostura* [means](https://www.aulete.com.br/compostura):

> *Comportamento comedido, educado, adequado a uma situação*
> [Restrained, polite, appropriate behavior in a given situation]

Being thus close to "[composure](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/composure)" (calmness; coolness; self-possession), and while losing it means "to become upset" in general, in the right context it can mean "to anger", for instance:

> *Perdi a compostura e gritei com ele.*
> [I lost my temper and yelled at him.]

Answer (score 4):

**Mesmo parecendo que elas tenham o mesmo significado, elas não tem.**

*Calma: serenidade de ânimo ou de disposição; relaxamento.*

*Temperamento: conjunto dos traços psicológicos e morais que determinam a índole de um indivíduo; modo de ser ou agir.*

Portanto cada um tem seu temperamento, podendo ele ser alegre, gentil e até mesmo calmo.

Ou seja, ao falar:

> Eu não estou perdendo meu temperamento

Eu estou afirmando que não estou perdendo meu temperamento, podendo o mesmo ser calmo, raivoso, feliz, etc.

E ao falar:

> Eu não estou perdendo minha calma

Eu estou afirmando que não estou perdendo minha calma, que é um estado emocional que representa ânimo, etc. que pode ou não fazer parte do seu temperamento.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você "está perdendo a calma" e exatamente como você descreveu, você está perdendo o controle das suas emoções, justificando aquela reação como algo praticamente incontrolável.